# oAuth in PHP to make 2 legged request

Tags: php, oauth, 2-legged

I am currently stuck trying to make requests to a service's api using a 2 legged oAuth request using PHP.

I am using the PHP library found here: http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/ and there seems to be absolutely no documentation anywhere online for using this library for a 2 legged request.

So currently from the service I have the following details:

- **$consumer_key** - *needs to be an empty string*
- **$consumer_secret** - *needs to be an empty string*
- **$access_token** - *my login name*
- **$access_token_secret** - *your generated application token*

And I want to be able to make a request to:

```
http://foo.com/api/test/whoami
```

To test that the authentication is working correctly so I can use the rest of the api.

Anybody got any pointers on how to use that php library to achieve this? or are there better methods for a simple 2 legged call like this?

Help!? :)

Comment: What do you mean by "needs to be an empty string" for the key/secret? You need some value there to be able to sign the request. Also, you usually wouldn't use the access token/token secret for a 2 legged request - you just sign the params with the secret

Comment: The service I am authenticating against requires an empty consumer key and consumer secret to work. I am not sure why this is the case, I have almost worked out the issues though, hopefully will be able to formulate an answer to my own question in an hour or two...

Comment: Was a solution found or was the OP hit by a bus? 1 or 2 hours has turned into 4 months :)

Comment: Nah, not hit by a bus. Although that would have been pretty apt given how annoying this process was. The project got cut due to this not working out and the budget blowing out.

Comment: There's actually some really good wiki on 2-legged requests for this specific library at http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/wiki/ConsumerHowTo but sorry to be a bit late :)

Answer (score 1):

This little example might help http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/04/a_twolegged_oauth_serverclient_example/

Comment: That example seem to request a key on itself, I seem no where any real API EndPoint, it's always the current script. Still looking for a plain simple example in pure php.

Answer (score 0):

You need just the consumer key and consumer secret to make authorized 2-legged oauth requests.

Download [`OAuthConsumer`](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/OAuth.php). (comment out the class `OAuthException` lines 6-8)

Code sample:

```
require_once 'OAuth.php';

$signatureMethod = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
$consumerKey = 'abc';
$consumerSecret = 'def';
$httpMethod = 'GET';
$url = 'http://path/to/endpoint';
$requestFields = array();

$oauthConsumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, NULL);
$oauthRequest = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($oauthConsumer, NULL, $httpMethod, $url, $requestFields);
$oauthRequest->sign_request($signatureMethod, $oauthConsumer, NULL);
```