# oauth2 and trusted sites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth-ruby, oauth-provider

is there any possibility to work with trusted sites (for example - sites of one developer) using oauth/oauth2 without confirmation of access to user data?

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking for is: Two-legged oauth

- [oAuth in PHP to make 2 legged request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496561/oauth-in-php-to-make-2-legged-request)
- http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/wiki/ConsumerHowTo